# Set $f(x)=\sum a_n x^n$ , $f$ is well defined on a nonempty set $A$ . If $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in A$ , can we prove that $a_n=0$ for all $n$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Set $f(x)=\sum a_n x^n$ ,$x \in C$ . $A$ is a subset of $C$ , $f$ is well defined on $A$ and only on $A$ ,$A-0$ is nonempty. If $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in A$ , can we prove that $a_n=0$ for all $n$ ?

My attempt:
If $B$ is an open set in $A$ , then $f$ has derivatives of all orders in $B$ . Since $f=0$ in $B$ , $f^{(n)}(x)=0$ in $B$ , this implies that $a_n = 0$ .
I'm not sure whether this proof is right , and I think there might have some other direct and rigorous proof .

Comment: I expect you are talking about $f$ being an infinite sum and $f$ is well-defined as in the series converges?

Comment: Yes , I am learning holomorphic function and power series right now .

Comment: If all you know is that $A$ is nonempty, this is very false. Consider the fact that $\sin(z)=0$ for $z\in \{k\pi: k\in\Bbb Z\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $f(x)=\sum a_nx^n$ converges exactly on $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ with $A\setminus\{0\}\neq\emptyset$. Let $r\in A\setminus\{0\}$. Because every infinite series has a radius of convergence, such that everything strictly within that radius makes the series converge, while everything strictly outside the radius makes the series diverge, we find that $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:|x|<|r|\}\subset A$. Because $|r|>0$ we find an interval where the series of $f$ converges.

For the final step, use the fact that an analytic function is entirely defined by its local behaviour. If an analytic function is identically $0$ on some non-discrete set (for example an interval) then all power series coefficients are $0$.

Comment: I have learned that  a holomorphic function is determined by its restriction to any open subset of its domain of definition , but this question seems so obvious , is there an primary proof of this ?

Comment: I remember being assigned to prove that an analytic function that vanishes on a non-discrete set must have all its power series coefficients $0$. This was pretty tedious. The proof is by induction. If the first $n$ terms are $0$, you can write $f(x)=a_nx^n+x^{n+1}g(x)$ for some analytic $g$. Then use some estimate to show that $g$ is negligable close to $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the set necessarily has to have any topology on it, so we can create counterexamples where the idea of an "open" set doesn't make any sense. For example, if $A=\mathbb{F}_2$, we can choose $a_0=0,a_1=a_2=1$ to get

$$x+x^2,$$

a polynomial which is identically $0$ on $\mathbb{F}_2$ but still has nonzero coefficients.

Comment: I believe the OP means that $f$ is well-defined on $A$ and only on $A$, so if $f(x)=x^2+x$ then $A=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @SmileyCraft The (implied) coefficient of $1$ here on each of $x$ and $x^2$ is the multiplicative identify in $\mathbb{F}_2$, not in $\mathbb{R}$. This polynomial is thus not defined anywhere outside of $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: @ SmileyCraft Yes , I will edit my question.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut I believe the OP also was talking about real-valued functions.

Comment: I want to talk about the real-valued function or the complexed function , but I'm not sure how to edit to show this .

Comment: @J.Guo Can you edit that into your question? The way it's phrased, especially given the question's analysis-y nature, doesn't make this clear.

Comment: @Carl Schildkraut I have already edit the question . This question occured when I read Stein's complex analysis , so I want to restrict the definition of $f$ into complex plane.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, I will assume $A$ is connected otherwise repeat the proof to each component. Observe first that if $f(z)$ is analytic on $A$, then it has an open neighborhood where it's analytic on so $A$ has infinitely many elements. I will even weaken the assumptions given and only use that we need a limit point inside $A$ (this is known as the identity theorem).

So by Heine-Borel, we know there exists a limit point $z^*$ inside $A$ such that $f(z_k) = 0$ for all $z_k \rightarrow z^{*}$. Then by analyticity \begin{equation} f(z) = a_k(z-z^*)^k + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{k+1+n}(z-z^*)^{k+1+n} \end{equation} where $k$ is chosen as the minimal integer such that $a_k \neq 0$ (otherwise we'll be done). Then \begin{equation} \frac{f(z)}{(z-z^*)^k} = a_k + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n+1+k}(z-z^*)^{n+1} \end{equation} But observe as for all $z_j$ the left hand side is 0, we see by continuity at $z=z^*$, the left hand side is 0. But at $z^*$ the sum is 0, so it implies $a_k$ must be zero; therefore, we have a contradiction. In particular, this shows that every point where the power series of $z^*$ converges is identically 0.

In particular we have shown that $U = \{z: f(z) = 0\}$ is open. But also since $f$ is continuous, so the pre-image of a singleton must be closed, which means $U$ is closed, open and non-empty. Then as $A$ is connected (or repeat the proof to each connected component), we see $U = A$. So $f$ is identically $0$ over A.